# Performance testing with 100 users: how to read links from CSV file in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, csv-file

I am using JMeter to do performance testing of a site.

I need to test various links of a site (no need to login) with 100 users and loop it for some number of times. I want to put those links in a CSV file, so that all the links to be tested are read from the file.

How do I accomplish this task using JMeter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14477375/993246

Answer (score 9):

I'll assume you're just using JMeter as a type of Web Crawler with a fixed set of pages to consume, and you're only measuring response times and http status.

1. Create a thread group of 100 users
2. Place a CSV Data Set Config under the thread group

   3. The CSV contains one URL per line
   4. The CSV loads into a parameter named "URL"
3. A HTTP Sampler is used where the hostname is set to ${URL}

   6. Specify any assertions you need, eg "200" http response
4. Run it and see how it goes

Heres some pictures of the setup in JMeter using the default samplers and config elements;

1. Create the threadgroup:
2. Create the CSV Reader
   [image]
3. Create the HTTP Sampler
   [image]
4. Have an assertion checking you get a decent response
   [image]
5. Optionally record the responses for review

## The CSV File i'm using looks like:

```
/
/
/robots.txt
/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi
/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi
/intl/en/options/
/intl/en/about/products/
/intl/en/about/products/
/history/optout?hl=en
com/history/optout?hl=en
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Access Log Sampler, it allows to read URL's which are stored in text file.

What you need to do, is:

1. Grab URL's which you need from site. This can be made with different tools. For Windows I've used Xenu's Link Sleuth, but there are a number of alternatives both for Mac and Linux.
2. Create new test plan in Jmeter and add Access Log Sampler to Thread Group;
3. Set up text file with URL's from  item 1 as Log file.

Access Log Sampler will take URL's one after another from log file.

More details in guide from our  [jmeter library](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65141-how-to-use-access-log-sampler-to-generate-traffic-)

P.S. I'm working for Blazemeter as developer of plugin for Jmeter.

Comment: Hi Dzmitry, as a general rule link-only answers are frowned upon. Could you provide a summary of the article here, so others will have information that gives them confidence that leaving the site will give them the answer they're looking for? Also, this is the second of three answers to link to the Blazemeter blog; if you have an affiliation with a particular site, [it must be made clear in the answer](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Answer (score 0):

I think, CSV just like

username, password
username1, password1
username2, password2
username3, password3
username4, password4
username5, password5

Comment: I dont think this provides an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can create a text file with with all the links you want to browse (one link per line). Load the file in JMeter bin Directory (links.txt)

In your JMeter Script you do the following:

1 - Add an HTTP Request Sampler
in the path you use /XYZ/**${_StringFromFile(links.txt)}**