# creation of 1000 different users using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have to create 1000 users at a time but when I execute test and after creation of 1st user, it gives an error that 'user already exsist' which is true. How can I create 1000 different users with different user names at a time.

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/14418/load-testing-using-jmeter-with-multiple-concurrent-users-account/14419#14419, this might help you! And this as well: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5577/performance-testing-with-100-users-how-to-read-links-from-csv-file-in-jmeter/5869#5869

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your use case you can consider using:

- [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function (it returns current JMeter thread number) as a prefix or postfix for username so different virtual users will generate different actual users
- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function to generate username out of pseudo-random characters
- [__counter() function or Counter test element](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) to generate incrementing number and use it as prefix or postfix